# Binaries that are not in the path are still found by shell, how?

Tags: shell, homebrew, binaryfiles

Context:
I have a macbook air M1

Example: I have homebrew installed and when I type

> which brew

I get

> /opt/homebrew/bin/brew

But when I check my path variables, this folder isn't there.

How is my shell still able to locate the brew binary?

EDIT: to clarify, I mean how am I still able to do something like

> brew --help

If the brew binary is not in my path

Comment: By using `which`?

Comment: @ScottHunter what I mean is if I try "brew --help" it correctly displays the help information for brew. However, brew is not in my path so how is my system even able to execute this command.

Comment: Try `type brew` instead of `which brew` to see if you have aliased it. Also, you may have changed your `PATH` (to exclude `/opt/homebrew/bin`) since it was last hashed, so try `hash -r` and then `type brew` again and see if your shell can still find it.